# F# extended Euclidian algorithm with Continuations question

Tags: functional-programming, f#, continuations

I am new to F# and haven't done functional programming since I was an undergraduate, but I've been trying teach myself. I wrote a naive recursive Extended Euclidean implementation, which works just fine, and am now trying again but with continuations.

I walked through the code by hand twice with a small example and got the correct answer, but when I run it through the interpreter I am not getting the same result, so I'm clearly misunderstanding something I am trying to do.

I ran eea 7 3 by hand, and the (correct) result I computed was (1, 1, -2)

But when I run it in the interpreter I get

```
eea 7 3;;
val it : int * int * int = (1, 0, 1)
```

Here's my implementation:

```
let eea a b = 
    let rec contEEA a b f = 
        match b with
        | 0 -> f () (a,1,0)
        | _ -> 
            contEEA b (a%b) (fun () t ->
                let (d,x',y') = t
                (d, y', x'-(y'*(a/b)))
            )
    contEEA a b (fun () t -> t)
```

For reference the naive approach, straight from a textbook, is

```
let rec eea_gcd a b =
    match b with
    | 0 -> (a, 1, 0)
    | _ -> 
        let d, x', y' = eea_gcd b (a % b)
        (d, y', x'-(y'*(a/b)))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your continuation-based version is always doing exactly one iteration (the last one). When you make the recursive call, your continuation just straight up returns the result instead of "returning" it to the previous call by passing to the previous continuation.

So the call sequence goes like this:

1. `eea 7 3`
2. `contEEA 7 3 (fun () t -> t)`
3. `b <> 0` ==> second case matches
4. `contEEA 3 1 (fun () t -> ... (d, y', ...))`
5. `b <> 0` ==> second case matches
6. `contEEA 1 0 (fun () t -> ... (d, y', ...))`
7. `b = 0` ==> first case matches
8. The continuation is called `f () (1, 1, 0)`
9. The continuation calculates result `(1, 0, 1 - (0*(3/1)) = (1, 0, 1)` and immediately returns it

What you *want* to do instead is when the first continuation calculates the result of `(1, 0, 1)` it should pass it to the *previous* continuation, so that it may carry on the calculations from there, ultimately passing the result to the very first continuation `fun () t -> t`, which returns it back to the consumer.

To do that, replace this line:

```
(d, y', x'-(y'*(a/b)))
```

With this:

```
f (d, y', x'-(y'*(a/b)))
```

---

**Also, a few notes on some other aspects.**

1. The first parameter of the continuation (the unit, `()`) is not necessary, since it's never actually used (and how can it be?). You can lose it.
2. After removing the unit parameter, the first continuation becomes `fun t -> t`, which has a special name `id` (aka "the identity function")
3. Rather than destructure the triple with a `let`, you can do it right in the parameter declaration. Parameters can be patterns!

Applying all of the above, as well as the actual problem fix, here's a better version:

```
let eea a b = 
    let rec contEEA a b f = 
        match b with
        | 0 -> f (a,1,0)
        | _ -> 
            contEEA b (a%b) (fun (d,x',y') -> 
                f (d, y', x'-(y'*(a/b)))
            )
    contEEA a b id
```